# How to configure a physical naming strategy in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I’m learning Java and Hibernate. Right now, I’m having trouble understanding how to use a custom physical naming strategy: While the `PhysicalNamingStrategy` object is indeed instantiated, the `toPhysicalTableName` or `toPhysicalColumnName` methods are never called – not that I can see with a debugger, at least.

Versions: Java 1.8, Hibernate 5.2.10.Final, on macOS 10.12.

Here’s a minimal project:

```
@Entity
public class Cake {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String FLAVOUR;
    private int sErViNg;

    public Cake(String name, String flavour, int serving) {
        this.name = name;
        this.FLAVOUR = flavour;
        this.sErViNg = serving;
    }

    // getters and setters
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Transaction tx = null;

        try (
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ) {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Cake cake = new Cake("Molten Chocolate Cake", "chocolate", 1);
            session.save(cake);

            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if ( tx != null  ) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy
    extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements Serializable {

    public static final AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy INSTANCE
        = new AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(name.getText().toUpperCase(), name.isQuoted());
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(name.getText().toUpperCase(), name.isQuoted());
    }
}
```

---

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/cake</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy">com.example.AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy</property>
        <mapping class="com.example.Cake"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

Here’s the table I get:

```
[cake]> SELECT * FROM cake;
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| id | FLAVOUR   | name                  | sErViNg |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
|  0 | chocolate | Molten Chocolate Cake |       1 |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
```

I would expect:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| ID | FLAVOUR   | NAME                  | SERVING |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
|  0 | chocolate | Molten Chocolate Cake |       1 |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: Edited in with as much detail I have on hand. Minor versions later.

Comment: It seems like your original code / configuration ought to work. I'm assuming you've double-checked the fully qualified path to `AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy` was correct in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: @SteveChambers I did. Whenever it is not, hibernate rightfully grumbles about `AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy` not being an instance of `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't very well documented but unfortunately it seems Hibernate doesn't support that particular property being set in hibernate.cfg.xml. To quote from [a very old Hibernate forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=934731&view=next):

> You can set the properties given Environment.java class only in
>   hibernate.properties or hibernate.cfg.xml. Rest of the properties like
>   NamingStrategy has to be configured with Configuration class.

So would recommend removing the property and instead setting this in code on the Configuration instance, as proposed by Shiv Raghuwanshi.

Answer (score 3):

You can set in configuration also.

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Transaction tx = null;

    try (
            Configuration configuration =new Configuration();
            configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new AllCapsPhysicalNamingStrategy());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    ) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Cake cake = new Cake("Molten Chocolate Cake", "chocolate", 1);
        session.save(cake);

        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if ( tx != null  ) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah ah! this works, but replacing `.setPhysicalNamingStrategy` by `.setProperty` doesn’t. But I can’t set whatever I want there either. Whenever I set a class that is not a PhysicalNamingProperty (in the XML or with setProperty), I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Cake cannot be cast to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the your configuration. It is just that bootstrapping hibernate using `Configuration` object requires you to set *some* of the config property on configuration object itself. These configuration specified via properties will get ignored.

Also, bootstrapping hibernate using Configuration object is considered as "legacy" way ([as per official hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap)) and [newer way](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native) is recommended of bootstrapping the hibernate as shown below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transaction tx = null;

        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // using "hibernate.cfg.xml"
                .build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).buildMetadata();
        try (
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();) {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Cake cake = new Cake("Molten Chocolate Cake", "chocolate", 1);
            session.save(cake);

            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

This will pick the Physical naming strategy specified as hibernate property in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.